# Is the difference between these two evals explained with constant folding?

Tags: perl, package, symbols, microbenchmark, constantfolding

Given these two evals which only change `Module::FOO()` and `FOO()`.

```
# Symbols imported, and used locally.
eval qq[ 
  package Foo$num;
  Module->import();
  my \$result = Module::FOO() * Module::FOO();
] or die $@;

# Symbols imported, not used locally referencing parent symbol.
eval qq[ 
  package Foo$num;
  Module->import();
  my \$result = FOO() * FOO();
] or die $@;
```

why would the top block take up **substantially** less space? The script and output are reproduced below,

## Script

```
package Module {
  use v5.30;
  use warnings;
  use constant FOO => 42; 
  use Exporter 'import';
  our @EXPORT = ('FOO');
}


package main {
  use v5.30;
  use autodie;
  use warnings;

  $|=1;
  say "Our PID is $$";

  for my $num ( 0..1e5 ) { 
    eval qq[ 
      package Foo$num;
      Module->import();
      my \$result = Module::FOO() * Module::FOO();
    ] or die $@;
    eval qq[
      package Foo$num;
      Module->import();
      my \$result = FOO() * FOO();
    ] or die $@;
  }

  say "DONE";

  _debug();

}

sub _debug {
  open my $fh, "<", "/proc/$$/status";
  while ( <$fh> ) { 
    next unless /Rss/;
    print;
  }
}
```

## Results

### Package (namespace) qualified

```
RssAnon:      78896 kB
RssFile:       5220 kB
RssShmem:         0 kB
```

### Locally imported

```
RssAnon:     168180 kB
RssFile:       5496 kB
RssShmem:         0 kB
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a result of the constant folding inside of Perl. This can be demonstrated with the following example from `haarg` on `irc.freenode.net/#perl`,

```
use strict;
use warnings;

package Module {
  use constant FOO => 42;
  use Exporter 'import';
  our @EXPORT = ('FOO');
}

my $subs = {
  loc => sub {
    package Foo;
    Module->import();
    my $result = FOO() * FOO();
  },
  fq => sub {
    package Foo;
    Module->import();
    my $result = Module::FOO() * Module::FOO();
  },
};

use Data::Dumper;
$Data::Dumper::Deparse = $Data::Dumper::Indent = 1;
print Dumper($subs);
```

That will result in,

```
$VAR1 = {
  'loc' => sub {
      package Foo;
      use warnings;
      use strict;
      'Module'->import;
      my $result = FOO() * FOO();
  },
  'fq' => sub {
      package Foo;
      use warnings;
      use strict;
      'Module'->import;
      my $result = 1764;
  }
};
```

You can see one of them has,

```
my $result = FOO() * FOO();
```

While the other has,

```
my $result = 1764;
```

You can get constant folding in both if the module is declared and the import is done in the compiler phase (in the case of a sub compilation), or before the execution in the case of a stringy-eval, like this

```
BEGIN {

    package Module {
      use constant FOO => 42;
      use Exporter 'import';
      our @EXPORT = ('FOO');
    }
    package Foo { Module->import() }

}
```